# Fetching Indexnames from Table with Cursor

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I would like to fetch all existing indexes (Bitmap Index Joins) from a table with a cursor and drop them. Well and the other way around, if and index does not exists, create them.

So far I was doing this with a procedure:

```
DECLARE
  COUNT_INDEXES INTEGER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO COUNT_INDEXES
  FROM USER_INDEXES
  WHERE INDEX_NAME = 'IDXNAME' ;

  IF COUNT_INDEXES > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX IDXNAME';
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: That's not going to work, of course, where an index supports a unique or primary key constraint -- you'll have to disable or drop the constraint first.

Comment: when you drop a bitmap index join you dont have to disble the constraints

Comment: Quite so, because a bitmap join index is not associated with any constraints.

Comment: I just saw, I didnt mention BIJ.... sry ;)

Answer (score 1):

here you go

```
declare
    cursor c_idx is 
        select  index_name 
        from    user_indexes 
        where   table_name = 'my_table_name';
begin 
    for x in c loop 
        execute immediate 'drop index '|| x.index_name;
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script, that drops all the indexes of a chosen table. For re-creating them, you have to provide some more information. Do you want to create a index on every column?

```
DECLARE
  l_table_name varchar2(20) := 'MY_TABLE'; 
BEGIN
  FOR r_idx IN
    SELECT INDEX_NAME
    FROM   USER_INDEXES
    WHERE  TABLE_NAME = l_table_name;
  LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX ' || r_idx.INDEX_NAME;
  END;
END;
```

Comment: I want to create Bitmap Index Joins on every column from a Dimension table: i.e.: create bitmap index on tbl_1(dim_column1, column2 ....) from tbl1, tbl2 where tbl1.id = tbl2.id LOCAL. In total there are about 5 indexes